# Syanpse code is not dropping the columns from the array list replaceCols from a Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, arraylist, drop

replaceCols=[
"LEI",
"Entity_LegalName",
"Entity_LegalAddress_FirstAddressLine",
"Entity_LegalAddress_City",
"Entity_LegalAddress_Country",
"Entity_HeadquartersAddress_FirstAddressLine",
"Entity_HeadquartersAddress_City",
"Entity_HeadquartersAddress_Country",
"Entity_RegistrationAuthority_RegistrationAuthorityID",
"Entity_LegalJurisdiction",
"Entity_LegalForm_EntityLegalFormCode",
"Entity_EntityStatus",
"Registration_InitialRegistrationDate",
"Registration_LastUpdateDate",
"Registration_RegistrationStatus",
"Registration_NextRenewalDate",
"Registration_ManagingLOU",
"Registration_ValidationSources"
]

#### Dataframe df has the above column plus many others after reading a csv source file.

df_W = df.drop(str(col(c).alias(c) for c in replaceCols))

#### The code is syntactically correct but is unable to drop the Dataframe columns mentioned in the ArrayList replaceCols.

Comment: Resolved :

df_W = df.drop(*replaceCols)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

df_W = df.drop(*replaceCols)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).